# GCP Load Balancer Response 503 When Upload File

Tags: google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I have a backend that processes a file. The file is uploaded from a client (Apache HTTP Client) by POST (multipart file). The size of the file is 30kb (average) and the load balancer sometimes responds with a 503 status for some POST. The max simultaneous uploads is 80.
Any idea how to fix that? Thanks!

According to GCP documentation the response status is generated by the load balancer. I checked the field "statusDetails" in the log.